# Is moving a window with SetWindowPos the 'normal way' to do?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am wondering if, in order to move a (ms-windows-)window with the Win32 API 20 px to the right and 40 px downwards, the following
function call would be how to do it:

```
SetWindowPos(
  /* hWnd             */  hChildDlg2, 
  /* hWndInsertAfter  */ (HWND) -1,
  /* X                */ 20,
  /* Y                */ 40,
  /* cx               */ -1,
  /* cy               */ -1,
  /* uFlags           */  SWP_NOSIZE |  // Ignore cx, cy
                          SWP_NOZORDER  // and hWndInsertAfter
);
```

I ask because it seems to me that there could be a function only taking a `HWND` and an `x` and `y` as parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the normal way and the window will get a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message (with the parameters that changed) There is also the older [`MoveWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx) but it is less flexible and actually forces you to set the size.

To properly save and restore window sizes you should use `GetWindowPlacement` and `SetWindowPlacement` respectively.

Comment: Looks like `SetWindowPos` forces you to set the Z-Order

Comment: @mikew no, use SWP_NOZORDER

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's pretty much how it's done. You should prefer to use [`SetWindowPos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx) since it gives you quite a bit of control over how the window should be moved/resized.

I typically use it like this (part of a small framework I wrote):

```
// Window member function
void Window::Move(int x, int y)
{
    if(hwnd != 0)
    {
        ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, x, y, 0, 0, 
            SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }
}
```

There's also a [`MoveWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534.aspx) function that does pretty much the same thing. With the `SetWindowPos()` function available, [it's now more of a convenience function than anything else](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090323-00/?p=18733).

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [`MoveWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534.aspx)?

It takes hwnd, x, y, width, height, since there's no `SWP_NOSIZE` flag, it's actually more complicated to use it to just move the window, since you also have to fetch the size.